# Convert Remote HTML tempalte to PDF in django

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, pdf

I am trying to convert HTML(hosted on a remote server) to pdf and then save in the Django model.

what I tried till now.

```
def convert_html_to_pdf(template, context, filename):
    response = requests.get(template)
    template = Template(response.content)

    html = template.render(Context(context))

    f = NamedTemporaryFile()
    f.name = '/' + user + '/' + str(filename)
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(template.encode('UTF-8')), f)

    if not pdf.err:
        return File(f)
    return False
```

```
file = pdf_docs.convert_html_to_pdf(
    template='https://www.example.com/sample.html',
    context={'name': 'John Smith'},
    filename='example.pdf',
)
```

In response, only the template URL is printed on PDF, not the content.

Comment: This is the rendered result `html = template.render(Context(context))` so use that here `pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode('UTF-8')), f)`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a function called `print`. You can use the print method to convert the HTML to PDF. Here, is the code snippet to convert HTML to PDF. In addition, you can hide the text elements in JS before converting the HTML to pdf so that you will only get the template printed.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Convert HTML to PDF</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btnPrint").live("click", function () {
            var divContents = $("#dvContainer").html();
            var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
            printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
            printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            printWindow.document.write(divContents);
            printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.print();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    <div id="dvContainer">
        This content needs to be printed.
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Print Div Contents" id="btnPrint" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```